# Use every top level domain for content script matches in firefox addon

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, manifest

I want to be able to use every top level domain without having to manually add them all

but when i use * it gives me an error when trying to add the extension

is there any way to make this work?

```
  "content_scripts":
  [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.google.*/*"],
      "js":["js/jquery.min.js", "js/content_script.js"]
    }
  ],
```

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

So i looked it up and it's actually not possible as of now to do it cleanly with matches

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/njkDwIF7WDc

so i settled for an if statement in my content script

```
if (location.href.indexOf("google.") !== -1) {
```

it's the "cleanest" thing i can come up with
it's not perfect but better than adding all google TPD's manually with a 50 item array

Comment: As you can see in the documentation of the content script you can use include_globs. An example for google: [How to load a content script on all Google (international) pages?](//stackoverflow.com/a/16187588)